PATCH API Endpoint Returns 404 via Swagger but 405 When Hit Directly in Production Environment
I have developed a Spring Boot application that includes a PATCH endpoint. The endpoint works perfectly in local and UAT environments, but there is an issue in the production environment where:

The endpoint is visible in the Swagger UI and the request URL is correct.

When I try to hit the API via Swagger, it results in a 404 error.

When I directly hit the endpoint URL from a browser, it returns a 405 Method Not Allowed error.

There are no error logs in the application logs when the issue occurs.

Other GET and POST endpoints are visible in Swagger and work fine in production.


What I Suspect:

The 405 error when hitting the endpoint directly from the browser suggests that the server (or reverse proxy) may not be configured to handle PATCH requests.
The 404 error in Swagger might indicate the request is not reaching the application correctly or is being blocked/redirected by middleware or proxy configurations.
The fact that GET and POST endpoints work fine in production suggests the issue is specific to the handling of PATCH requests.

What I Need Help With:

Why does the PATCH endpoint give different errors (404 in Swagger, 405 in direct browser calls)?
Could this be related to the reverse proxy or server configuration (e.g., NGINX not allowing PATCH requests)?
What additional steps should I take to debug this issue, given there are no error logs?

Here is my SecurityConfig file:
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.HeadersConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {
    private final FilterChainExceptionHandler filterChainExceptionHandler;
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable()) 
                .headers(headers -> headers
                        .contentSecurityPolicy(csp -> csp
                                .policyDirectives("default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'; style-src 'self'; frame-ancestors 'none';")
                        ) //CSP implementation
                )
                .headers(headers -> headers
                        .frameOptions(HeadersConfigurer.FrameOptionsConfig::deny) // Deny framing to prevent clickjacking
                )
                .addFilterBefore(filterChainExceptionHandler, LogoutFilter.class) 
                .authorizeHttpRequests(requests -> requests
                        .anyRequest().permitAll() 
                );

        return http.build();
    }
}

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
